# Android: How to set WebView dimension in device pixels?

Tags: android, webview, device, html, pixel

I have a HTML page with 100% x 200px width and height respectively.
I want to display this page inside a WebView, and that WebView should be exactly 200 device pixels tall, so that I can see my page without scale just perfectly fit into the view.

How can I set the WebView height in DEVICE PIXELS and load the HTML page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In code

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourwebview);
wv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200));
```

or the same in XML

```
<WebView android:layout_height="200px" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks alextsc, I did what you said using XML, and also:
In my HTML page specified the viewport to be 200px: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="height=200px" />`

So, now I have:
a. WebView with height=200px
b. the viewport of webview is having also 200px in height
c. my table is still 200px tall
Result: My table is taller than the webview's occupied space on the screen and i am scrolling...

I'm trying to achieve smth very simple and yet it is so difficult with Android!

Comment: Ok, my problem was that the LinearLayot was stretching the WebView. Nevertheless, your post answers the original question.

Comment: Since `ViewGroup.FILL_PARENT` is deprecated, I'm assuming `ViewGroup.MATCH_PARENT` would work as well?